# SQL to Replace Specific Text in Field Not Working

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, replace

I'm trying to make text replacements on a particular FIELD in an Access.accdb and it is not working.  No errors, just no change.  I'm working in vb.net.

I'm using the following:

```
    Dim AccessConn As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
    AccessConn = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=c:\temp\TEST.accdb")

    AccessConn.Open()
    Dim strSQL As String = "UPDATE [TEMPData] SET [Filetype] = REPLACE([Filetype], 'PDF', 'XXX')"
    Dim AccessCommand As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(strSQL, AccessConn)
    AccessConn.Close()
```

My ULTIMATE goal is to make a text replacement of a substring in a FIELD (e.g. "---PDF---" is changed to "---XXX---".  But as it stands now, I can't make any replacement.

I appreciate any kind of help, thanks

Comment: You are creating `OleDbCommand` object but not executing it.

Comment: I think you will have to bring the data into vb.net and do the replacement there. Then update the database. Retrieve to a DataTable with a primary key and the Filetype field. Loop through the rows updating the data then created a DataAdapter and call update.